# How to pass values in an array from the controller to view

Tags: php, laravel

I m new to Laravel and I am trying to pass values from a controller which I have received from a `<form>` to a view and display the same in text boxes. Although, I have figured out how to do the same using method chaining but I would like to pass the values using an array and show the same into the textboxes in the view.

#### What I expect to do?

In the `controller`, instead of method chaining:

`return view('showvalues')->with(['name'=>$name, 'address'=>$address]);`

#### Code so far,

`controller`

```
 public function showvalues(Request $request)
    {
        $name=$request->get('name');
        $address=$request->get('address');
        $pass=$request->get('password');
        $arr=array("$name","$address","$pass");

        return view('showvalues')->with('name',$name)->with('address',$address);
    }
```

Show values in `showvalues` view:

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>
            Show Value Page.
        </h1>
        <input type="text" name="n1" value="<?php echo $name;?>" /><br>
        <input type="text" name="n3" value="<?php echo $address;?>" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @Don'tDownvoteMe controller file you can pass below line in return view like this
return view('showvalues')->with(['name' => $name, 'address' => $address, 'pass' => $pass]); AND then,
showvalues.blade.php easily access $name,$address and $pass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `compact` method as the second argument to `view`:

```
public function showvalues(Request $request)
{
    $name = $request->get('name');
    $address = $request->get('address');
    $pass = $request->get('password');

    return view('showvalues', compact('name', 'address', 'pass'));
}
```

The variables will be available in your view file by the same name, you can display them like:

```
{{ $name }}
{{ $address }}
{{ $pass }}
```

Comment: How to display the values of this array in the view?

Comment: This is new to me. I just usually create an array for my data and pass that array in my view. Thank you for this

Comment: `compact()` creates an array of all the elements then why is it that in the view, we are able to access all these elements using `echo`?

Comment: It's equivalent to writing `array('name' => $name, 'address' => $address, 'pass' => $pass)`, the blade engine will use the array keys to create variables and assign to them their respective value in the array.

Comment: Even if you don't use blade, with simple PHP, the values can be fetched using `echo` instead of `print_r`

Answer (score 2):

Pass array as second argument to `view()`:

```
return view('showvalues', ['name'=>$name, 'address'=>$address]);
```

Btw, did you try to open [Laravel's manual](https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade)?

Comment: How to display the values of this array in the view?

Comment: The same as you do with `with`. Please, __be kind__ and open Laravel manual.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to return all `form` inputs with `compact` function.

**Controller**

```
public function showvalues(Request $request)
{
    $form = $request->all();

    return view('showvalues', compact('form'));
}
```

**View**

```
{{ $form['name'] }}
{{ $form['address'] }}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, although I haven't tried this one but I guess, it saves time.

Comment: It's very useful if form element change or create.

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
return view('showvalues')->withName($name);
```

Or

```
return view('showvalues')->with(['name'=>$name]);
```